# Absolute Positioned Dynamic Buttons Stacking?

Tags: css, button, positioning

So I'm making a jQuery slideshow using the jQuery cycle plugin.

Part of the code generates an `<input type="button">` with a value from `1` to `i` (where `i` equals the total number of slides)

I'm trying to style these buttons so that they appear on top of the image in the slideshow. However when I try to absolute position the buttons they all stack on top of each other. I understand why this is happening, I just don't understand how to get around it.

This is how I'm targeting the buttons the JavaScript is generating.

```
input[type=button] {
position: absolute;
left: 400px;
}
```

How do I prevent the buttons from stacking?

Comment: Do you generate this buttons or are they generated by Cycle? Latter case: there are many options and demos maybe closer to what you want to achieve. Former case: why not generate them before or after the slides, in their own container? Also: please post relevant HTML code, positioning without HTML code is pretty hard ;)

Answer (score 1):

If Position is absolute, you must define left and top for each separately, else it will stack up,

Or you may use `position:relative` with `margin:5px; float:left;`

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying absolute positioning, try floating the image.

```
input[type=button] {
position: relative;
float: center;
padding: 10px;
}
```

This should eliminate the stacking and you can also easily add borders and customize this to be whatever you want. This is just a general description of what I thought was necessary .

Comment: Wow thanks that worked great! One last question. I'm not sure if I should start a new topic for this though. So now I have the buttons positioned properly, they're displayed in a horizontal row. How would you go about making them display in a vertical row?

Answer (score 0):

I used  tags instead of buttons, but I don't think it should make too much of a difference. Anyways, if you want to go about making it vertical, I would just go like this:

HTML:

```
<h1>Example</h1><br />
        <h1>Example1</h1><br />
        <h1>Example2</h1><br />
```

CSS:

```
h1{
      position: relative;
      float: none;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This is fairly simple CSS work so it won't take you too far, but this is a good start. Also, I would never recommend using absolute positioning unless you're only dealing with one object instead of several since it creates a stacked look. Hope this helps.